# Can you override the single string parameter constructor for Exception?

Tags: exception

I want to declare a custom exception class that takes a message and also does some custom tracing:

```
public MyException extends Exception{

    public MyException(String msg){
        MyTracing.trace(msg);
        this(msg);
    }
}
```

I couldn't make this work so I created a static factory method that first traces then calls my `new MyException` instead, I'm just building up familiarity with apex and wondered if anyone could tell me whether or not this can be done without a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this, because constructors cannot be overridden. As a workaround, I would suggest the following alternative:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException withMessage(String msg) {
        MyTracing.trace(msg);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This changes your invocation to:

```
throw new MyException().withMessage('Divide by zero makes me sad');
```

Or, you could just add another parameter to the mix. For example:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String msg, Boolean reserved) {
        this(msg);
        MyTracing.trace(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, Yes this is my static method: public class MyException extends Exception {
    public static MyException create(String msg) {
        MyTracing.trace(msg);
        return new MyException(msg);
    }
}